# Axios onUploadProgress not called on Nuxtjs project when nuxt@pwa and nuxt@firebase modules installed

Tags: firebase, axios, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

A noticed that onUploadProgress from axios are not being called at all on my Nuxt.js Project. After some debugging I found out it is related to the  "@nuxtjs/pwa" and   "@nuxtjs/firebase" modules. I use firebase auth, and the PWA module uses a service worker to take care of SSR auth and inject the auth token on outgoing requests.

This modules are interfering somehow on the axios onUploadProgress. I use axios to upload files to other Apis.

Once I remove the "@nuxtjs/pwa" module the onUploadProgress from axios gets called normally.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

The versions of the modules:

```json
"@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
"@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.6.1",
"@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
firebase: {
 ....
  services: {
    auth: {
      ssr: true,
      persistence: 'local',
      initialize: {
        onAuthStateChangedAction: 'auth/onAuthStateChangedAction',
        subscribeManually: false,
      },
    },
    firestore: true,
    functions: true,
  },
}
pwa: {
  meta: false,
  icon: false,
  workbox: {
    importScripts: ['/firebase-auth-sw.js'],
    dev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  },
},
```

Axios upload

```js
const asset = await $axios.post(uploadUrl, formData, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    console.log('onUploadProgress');
    const prog = parseInt(
      Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100)
    );

    progress(prog);
  },
});
```

the console.log isn't called at all.

`firebase-auth-sw`

```js
const ignorePaths = ["\u002F__webpack_hmr","\u002F_loading","\u002F_nuxt\u002F"]

importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js'
)
importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js'
)
```

```js
firebase.initializeApp({"apiKey":"AIzaSyDUjfwaCRNG72CaPznknOfbNLySkFQvfrs","authDomain":"j-a-developer-web-site.firebaseapp.com","projectId":"j-a-developer-web-site","storageBucket":"j-a-developer-web-site.appspot.com","messagingSenderId":"393360816421","appId":"1:393360816421:web:75c43cac27032d924502cc"})

// Initialize authService
const authService = firebase.auth()

/**
 * Returns a promise that resolves with an ID token if available.
 * @return {!Promise<?string>} The promise that resolves with an ID token if
 *     available. Otherwise, the promise resolves with null.
 */
const getIdToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const unsubscribe = authService.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      unsubscribe()
      if (user) {
        // force token refresh as it might be used to sign in server side
        user.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {
          resolve(idToken)
        }, () => {
          resolve(null)
        })
      } else {
        resolve(null)
      }
    })
  })
}

const fetchWithAuthorization = async (original, idToken) => {
  // Clone headers as request headers are immutable.
  const headers = new Headers()
  for (let entry of original.headers.entries()) {
    headers.append(entry[0], entry[1])
  }

  // Add ID token to header.
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + idToken)

  // Create authorized request
  const { url, ...props } = original.clone()
  const authorized = new Request(url, {
    ...props,
    mode: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'manual',
    headers
  })

  return fetch(authorized)
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url)

  const expectsHTML = event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')

  const isSameOrigin = self.location.origin === url.origin
  const isHttps = (self.location.protocol === 'https:' || self.location.hostname === 'localhost' || self.location.hostname === '127.0.0.1')

  const isIgnored = ignorePaths.some(path => {
    if (typeof path === 'string') {
      return url.pathname.startsWith(path)
    }

    return path.test(url.pathname.slice(1))
  })

  // https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/465
  if (!expectsHTML || !isSameOrigin || !isHttps || isIgnored) {
      event.respondWith(fetch(event.request))

    return
  }

  // Fetch the resource after checking for the ID token.
  // This can also be integrated with existing logic to serve cached files
  // in offline mode.
  event.respondWith(
    getIdToken().then(
      idToken => idToken
        // if the token was retrieved we attempt an authorized fetch
        // if anything goes wrong we fall back to the original request
        ? fetchWithAuthorization(event.request, idToken).catch(() => fetch(event.request))
        // otherwise we return a fetch of the original request directly
        : fetch(event.request)
    )
  )
})

// In service worker script.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(clients.claim())
})
```

`sw`

```js
const options = {"workboxURL":"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/workbox-cdn@5.1.4/workbox/workbox-sw.js","importScripts":["/firebase-auth-sw.js"],"config":{"debug":true},"cacheOptions":{"cacheId":"J.A-Developer-Web-Site-dev","directoryIndex":"/","revision":"qIA7lTEhJ6Mk"},"clientsClaim":true,"skipWaiting":true,"cleanupOutdatedCaches":true,"offlineAnalytics":false,"preCaching":[{"revision":"qIA7lTEhJ6Mk","url":"/?standalone=true"}],"runtimeCaching":[{"urlPattern":"/_nuxt/","handler":"NetworkFirst","method":"GET","strategyPlugins":[]},{"urlPattern":"/","handler":"NetworkFirst","method":"GET","strategyPlugins":[]}],"offlinePage":null,"pagesURLPattern":"/","offlineStrategy":"NetworkFirst"}

importScripts(...[options.workboxURL, ...options.importScripts])

initWorkbox(workbox, options)
workboxExtensions(workbox, options)
precacheAssets(workbox, options)
cachingExtensions(workbox, options)
runtimeCaching(workbox, options)
offlinePage(workbox, options)
routingExtensions(workbox, options)

function getProp(obj, prop) {
  return prop.split('.').reduce((p, c) => p[c], obj)
}

function initWorkbox(workbox, options) {
  if (options.config) {
    // Set workbox config
    workbox.setConfig(options.config)
  }

  if (options.cacheNames) {
    // Set workbox cache names
    workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails(options.cacheNames)
  }

  if (options.clientsClaim) {
    // Start controlling any existing clients as soon as it activates
    workbox.core.clientsClaim()
  }

  if (options.skipWaiting) {
    workbox.core.skipWaiting()
  }

  if (options.cleanupOutdatedCaches) {
    workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches()
  }

  if (options.offlineAnalytics) {
    // Enable offline Google Analytics tracking
    workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize()
  }
}

function precacheAssets(workbox, options) {
  if (options.preCaching.length) {
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(options.preCaching, options.cacheOptions)
  }
}


function runtimeCaching(workbox, options) {
  const requestInterceptor = {
    requestWillFetch({ request }) {
      if (request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && request.mode === 'no-cors') {
        return new Request(request.url, { ...request, cache: 'default', mode: 'no-cors' })
      }
      return request
    },
    fetchDidFail(ctx) {
      ctx.error.message =
        '[workbox] Network request for ' + ctx.request.url + ' threw an error: ' + ctx.error.message
      console.error(ctx.error, 'Details:', ctx)
    },
    handlerDidError(ctx) {
      ctx.error.message =
        `[workbox] Network handler threw an error: ` + ctx.error.message
      console.error(ctx.error, 'Details:', ctx)
      return null
    }
  }

  for (const entry of options.runtimeCaching) {
    const urlPattern = new RegExp(entry.urlPattern)
    const method = entry.method || 'GET'

    const plugins = (entry.strategyPlugins || [])
      .map(p => new (getProp(workbox, p.use))(...p.config))

    plugins.unshift(requestInterceptor)

    const strategyOptions = { ...entry.strategyOptions, plugins }

    const strategy = new workbox.strategies[entry.handler](strategyOptions)

    workbox.routing.registerRoute(urlPattern, strategy, method)
  }
}

function offlinePage(workbox, options) {
  if (options.offlinePage) {
    // Register router handler for offlinePage
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp(options.pagesURLPattern), ({ request, event }) => {
      const strategy = new workbox.strategies[options.offlineStrategy]
      return strategy
        .handle({ request, event })
        .catch(() => caches.match(options.offlinePage))
    })
  }
}

function workboxExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}

function cachingExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}

function routingExtensions(workbox, options) {
  
}
```

store's `index.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({});

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit }, { res }) {
    // initialize the store with user if already authenticated
    if (res && res.locals && res.locals.user) {
      const {
        allClaims: claims,
        idToken: token,
        ...authUser
      } = res.locals.user;
      await dispatch('auth/onAuthStateChangedAction', {
        authUser,
        claims,
        token,
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Applied some formatting to make it far more readable.